# Detecting nearly simultaneous WhenEvents in NDSolve

Tags: numerical-integration, bugs, differential-equations

I am trying to solve a system of (many) coupled nonlinear ODEs. I need to decouple some of the equations (i.e. set the time derivatives of some of the dependent variables to zero) at various points in the time integration when particular criteria are reached. To do this, I am using `NDSolve` with equations that contain some terms multiplied by `DiscreteVariables` whose values (1 or 0) are controlled by `WhenEvents`. The problem is, some of the `WhenEvents` tend to occur at nearly simultaneous times, and `NDSolve` appears to have difficult detecting multiple simultaneous events without the use of a ridiculously small `MaxStepSize`.

I know that the `DiscreteVariables` functionality for `NDSolve` is new, as of v9, and I have found similar question at [mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/76777](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com.80bola.com/questions/76777/whenevent-error-in-ndsolve), although in a system without `DiscreteVariables`.

Here is a minimal working example (per Michael E2's first answer, note that we can use `Sow` and `Reap` to check that only one event is being triggered) that fails to evaluate both `WhenEvents`:

```
With[
 {
 ti = Log@100,
 tf = Log@(10^9),
 a0 = 3.05917*^7,
 b0 = 3.05242*^7
 },
 {{sol}, {evts}} = Reap@NDSolve[
  {
  a'[t] == (a[t] - b[t] s2[t]) s1[t],
  b'[t] == (-a[t] s1[t] + b[t]) s2[t],   
  a[tf] == a0^2,
  b[tf] == b0^2,  
  s1[tf] == 1,
  s2[tf] == 1,
  WhenEvent[Evaluate[a[t] > Exp[2 t]], {Sow["a" -> t], s1[t] -> 0}, "DetectionMethod" -> "Sign"],
  WhenEvent[Evaluate[b[t] > Exp[2 t]], {Sow["b" -> t], s2[t] -> 0}, "DetectionMethod" -> "Sign"]
  },
  {a, b, s1, s2},
  {t, ti, tf},
  DiscreteVariables -> {Element[s1, {0, 1}], Element[s2, {0, 1}]},
  Method -> Automatic,
  WorkingPrecision -> Automatic
  MaxStepSize -> Automatic,
  MaxSteps -> Infinity
 ]
]

(*
{{{a -> InterpolatingFunction[{{4.60517, 20.7233}}, <>], 
   b -> InterpolatingFunction[{{4.60517, 20.7233}}, <>], 
   s1 -> InterpolatingFunction[{{4.60517, 20.7233}}, <>], 
   s2 -> InterpolatingFunction[{{4.60517, 20.7233}}, <>]}},
 {{"b" -> 17.2351}}}
*)
```

The scales (`10^7`, `10^9`) are taken from my work, but the equations are much simplified. Both `s1` and `s2` should step from 1 to 0 as the system integrates down from `tf` to `ti`; however, usually only the `"b"` event triggering `s2`, the first one to occur, is recognized.

According to the documentation, the `"DetectionMethod" -> "Interpolation"` option for `WhenEvent` should be more "robust" against multiple events per step than the default option, but I actually generally get better behavior with the default `"DetectionMethod" -> "Sign"`.

Using more precision and a small step size does get the job done:

```
a0 = SetPrecision[3.05917*^7, 2 MachinePrecision],
b0 = SetPrecision[3.05242*^7, 2 MachinePrecision],
Method -> "ExplicitRungeKutta",
MaxStepSize -> 0.0001
```

However, this small of a step size (seems to require the step to be smaller than the time separation between events by about an order of magnitude) takes too much time for my big system of coupled equations and is not always successful.

I can also get both events to be evaluated if I set `"LocationMethod" -> "StepEnd"` in each `WhenEvent`, but that tends to produce moderate discontinuities in the solutions when I run it with my larger system (probably an interesting problem in itself). The fact that it works makes me suspect that the trouble has something to do with the order in which the `WhenEvents` are being evaluated (e.g. the event for `s2` is processed first, and the result of that evaluation causes the system not to recognize that the event for `s1` also occurs during that timestep). Giving each `WhenEvent` a different `"Priority"` doesn't help.

My question is: is there a robust way to ensure that all the `WhenEvents` are recognized (such that the decoupling variables `s1` and `s2` both go to zero) without resorting to a small timestep or pushing the effects of the decoupling to the end of the step via `"LocationMethod" -> "StepEnd"`?

**Update:** This appears to be a bug. I sent this in to Wolfram, and they acknowledged that "NDSolve is not behaving properly in this case", and forwarded it to their developers.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a workaround. I'm not sure why the variables `s1[t]`, `s2[t]` are not reset in my first answer (see edit history).  We can take care of things manually by making `s1` and `s2` numerical functions.

```
Block[{ti = Log@100, tf = Log@(10^9), a0 = 3.05917*^7, 
  b0 = 3.05242*^7, s1, s2, s10 = 1, s20 = 1},
 s1[t_?NumericQ] := s10; 
 s2[t_?NumericQ] := s20;
 {{sol}, {evts}} = 
  Reap@NDSolve[{a'[t] == (a[t] - b[t] s2[t]) s1[t], 
     b'[t] == (-a[t] s1[t] + b[t]) s2[t], a[tf] == a0^2, b[tf] == b0^2,
     WhenEvent[a[t] > Exp[2 t], Sow["a" -> t]; s10 = 0], 
     WhenEvent[b[t] > Exp[2 t], Sow["b" -> t]; s20 = 0]},
    {a, b}, {t, ti, tf}]

(*
  {{{a -> InterpolatingFunction[{{4.60517, 20.7233}}, <>], 
     b -> InterpolatingFunction[{{4.60517, 20.7233}}, <>]}},
   {{"b" -> 17.2351, "a" -> 17.2351}}}
*)
```

Comment: That is interesting. In your example it looks like both `WhenEvents` _are_ being evaluated, which is technically what I was asking for. However, if you look at the interpolation functions for `s1` and `s2` in the solution both are constant at 1, rather than going to 0 as they should (i.e only the first `Sow` action occurs?), which is what I need.

Comment: @Virgil I think you're right.  I didn't notice since graphs of `a` and `b`  flatten out at about the right time.  `NDSolve` does not like me today.  This is the second time things do not work as advertised.

Comment: Good use of `Reap` and `Sow`, though. I'm not sure why `NDSolve` sees both events if there is a `Sow` statement first in the `WhenEvent` action. The answer to the [question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/76777/whenevent-error-in-ndsolve) I referenced with this question seems to indicate that `WhenEvent` has different behavior for simple vs. compound action statements. I might be running in to that.

Comment: I have, of course, linked you to your own answer.

Comment: @Virgil, yes, I realized that.  So far everything else I've tried (other than the current aswer) either misses an event or fails to reset the variables.

Comment: Your workaround does work for me, although it is a pity that the `DiscreteVariables` functionality seems to be breaking. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Virgil, you're welcome.  If I happen to find something that works, I'll let you know.